# How to completely remove homebrew?

Tags: macos, homebrew

I am seeking for the equivalent of

```
rvm implode
```

In the Ruby rvm world `rvm implode` completely uninstalls everything ruby related installed via rvm, including rvm too.

Is there anything similar for homebrew? Or do I have to remove each package, then remove `/usr/local/Cellar` and look around for any other remains that have not been dealt with automatically?

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/82807/how-to-cleanly-remove-homebrew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [this script to uninstall homebrew](https://gist.github.com/mxcl/1173223) completely. It's safer to run each command separately, especially the **cd `brew --prefix`** to check if it suceeds.

From the [homebrew FAQ](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/FAQ):

> How do I uninstall Homebrew?
>
> If you installed to /usr/local then you can use the script in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/mxcl/1173223) to uninstall — it will only remove Homebrew and the stuff Homebrew installed leaving anything else in /usr/local alone.
>
> Provided you haven’t put anything else in Homebrew’s prefix (brew --prefix), you can generally just rm -rf that directory. This is because Homebrew won’t touch files outside its prefix.