# How to fix multiple errors when installing Homebrew on OSX Lion (mainly OSXFUSE and Mono related)

Tags: sound-volume, terminal, macos, homebrew

I'm trying to install Homebrew but I'm getting multiple errors when brew doctor is run.

I'm a complete noob at this and I've tried [uninstalling Homebrew](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/82807/how-to-cleanly-remove-homebrew) and re-installing, but still not working.

Here's what it shows:

```
Warning: /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework detected
This can be picked up by CMake's build system and likely cause the build to
fail. You may need to move this file out of the way to compile CMake.

Warning: Unbrewed dylibs were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected dylibs:
    /usr/local/lib/libmacfuse_i32.2.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libmacfuse_i64.2.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libmpg123.0.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libosxfuse_i32.2.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libosxfuse_i64.2.dylib

Warning: Unbrewed .la files were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected .la files:
    /usr/local/lib/libosxfuse_i32.la
    /usr/local/lib/libosxfuse_i64.la

Warning: Unbrewed .pc files were found in /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected .pc files:
    /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/osxfuse.pc
```

Could anyone help me? What is Mono? I don't remember installing it. How could I find out what programmes I use are using Mono? If they're not important, maybe I could un-install Mono? And it seems like a lot of other errors are based on OSXFUSE. Could I move those to another place? Is there another way other than un-installing it? Thanks a million.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this to fix the osxlibfuse warnings: https://gist.github.com/trinitronx/5437061

It should be compatible with Truecrypt which needs osxlibfuse.  If you have another program that needs them (doubtful) then this fix might mess it up.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I uninstalled OSXFUSE and uninstalled MONO and reinstalled it after I got the green light from "brew doctor". :) Thanks!